# I can choose both. {but only one?}

Tags: word-usage, determiners

Is there a way to say something like:

> I can choose **both**.

But with a strong implication of *choosing only **one*** of the two?

Of course I could say:

> Both are allowed.

---

Is **either** what I'm searching for?

Do

> I can choose either.
>
> Either will do.

suggest that only **one** has to be chosen?

Comment: _You can choose one or the other, but you can't have both_.

Comment: @J.R. that's what I want to express concisely, also being the one who has to choose

Comment: Are you looking for something like **mutually-exclusive selector** which means you can **only choose one from any number of possibilities** (whoever makes the selection is the **selector**)

Comment: @Peter Exactly. An example could be _which test you have to take in order to get something_. Turns out you are able to choose whichever you prefer, but you don't have to take _both_.

Comment: Is it "you don't have to take both" or "you can't take both"?

Comment: @DamkerngT. **can't**. But it would be interesting also to know if there is something specific for _don't have to_

Answer (score 1):

> I can choose either.
>
> Either will do.

Both of these imply one or the other. Either is exactly the word you are looking for.

> I can either take that test or this test.
>
> We can either go fishing or shopping.